# Where can I find the prettify color scheme Stack Exchange uses?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

Last night I came across this website for a piece of code I was having trouble with and I just love the color scheme you use to highlight C code.

I've been looking for a while now to see if I can find it somewhere, as I would like to use it myself. Is it available somewhere, by any chance?

Comment: http://www.colorcombos.com/

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange uses the [Google Code Prettify project](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for all syntax highlighting.

The specific CSS colors used for each class used in syntax markup are still site specific however; Stack Overflow uses:

```css
.str { color: #800000 }  /* string content */
.kwd { color: #00008b }  /* a keyword */
.com { color: #808080 }  /* a comment */
.typ { color: #2b91af }  /* a type name */
.lit { color: #800000 }  /* a literal value */
.pun { color: #000 }     /* punctuation */
.pln { color: #000 }     /* plain text */
.tag { color: #800000 }  /* a markup tag name */
.atn { color: #f00 }     /* a markup attribute name */
.atv { color: #00f }     /* a markup attribute value */
.dec { color: #800080 }  /* a declaration */
```

Site look and feel designs *are* copyrighted, but I don't think Stack Exchange would object awfully much if you reused those colours for syntax highlighting elsewhere.

Comment: I knew that Prettify was being used and of course I can just color pick the individual colors, but as you already said: this isn't very nice considering the copyright. I would prefer to get either the scheme/file or explicit permission to pick the individual colors.

Comment: I'd say using these colours falls under fair use. Prettify automatically marks out what tokens get what class, so it is not as if the design is arduous.

Comment: As for the 'scheme'; the above CSS rules are *it*, plus print media rules.